# Python packaging tools not found after pythonpath change

Tags: python, pycharm, pythonpath

In my terminal, I typed: `export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/google_appengine:/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/:/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/yaml/"` and now my Pycharm isn't displaying any packages and libraries that I had previously.

All of my projects can still use the old libraries and packages that I had installed previously, but now I cannot install new ones, which is really strange.

This is the message that I receive:

[image]

When I click **Install packaging tools**, I get this error:

[image]

Comment: Do you have duplicate versions of python installed that share the same version?

Comment: Hey @DanielScott , I don't believe so. It's just `2.7` and `3.6`. My Conda version interpreter in Pycharm is saying I can do use `3.6`, `3.5`, `3.4` and `2.7`. I think I messed something up by installing Google App Engine or typing in that code that I describe above.

Comment: By any chance, did you install the google app engine with sudo?

Comment: Can you post the contents of `sudo gedit /etc/profile` if it isn't too sensitive?

Comment: @DanielScott I went into the directory and `./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh`

then `./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh`.

My final input was: export `PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/google_appengine:/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/:/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/yaml/"`

Comment: @DanielScott Here is the contents of `sudo gedit /etc/profile`: https://pastebin.com/ChERecMm

Comment: thanks. Can you print off the results from `anaconda2/bin/conda list` ? It appears that your pycharm is trying to point to an anaconda installation of python, and im curious if you will see your new modules in that list.

Comment: @DanielScott I ran into an error while doing that. https://pastebin.com/d2ku9kRC. `requests` is the most recent library that I;m working with. I also did download a forked version of `python-firebase` that could have messed up Pycharm, but that's a guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186331/discussion-between-daniel-scott-and-petar-luketina).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You installation of python is corrupted. Looks like your PATH variable took a beating in general, and now conda isn't properly recognized.

In this case, it is best to reinstall Anaconda with:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/Anaconda
bash Anaconda-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Comment: Yes, it finally worked! Thank you for you patience. I reinstalled PyCharm too to make sure I started fresh.